# Sharepoint Privileges

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

When checking in a document I execute a web service within the `ItemCheckingInEvent`.  In Dev, no problems.  I deployed the app out and it turns out I don't have enough privileges to read a configuration file.  My code reads a config file to create the WCF proxy.  The real issue is how can I get a return back from my function if I use the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` function?

For example:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{

      // exec service call

});

// need data from service call here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare your working object before the elevated delegate, and assign it inside:

```
object myServiceData = null;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
      myServiceData = DoServiceStuff();
});

//do things with myServiceData
```